# want to create an empty matrix of unknown dimension and append feature vectors

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scikit-image

I want to append HoG feature vectors to an empty matrix of unknown dimension. Is it required to specify the dimension of the matrix in advance? I have tried some code in python but it says all the input arrays must have same dimension.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.feature import hog
from skimage import data, exposure, img_as_float
from skimage import data
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg
import cv2
import glob


shape = (16576, 1)
X = np.empty(shape)
print X.shape
hog_image = np.empty(shape)
hog_image_rescaled = np.empty(shape)

for img in glob.glob("/home/madhuri/pythoncode/faces/*.jpg"):
   n= cv2.imread(img)
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(n, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
   hog_image = hog(gray, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16),     
                   cells_per_block=(3, 3), visualise=False)
   hog_image_rescaled = exposure.rescale_intensity(hog_image,
                                                   in_range=(0,10))  
   X = np.append(X, hog_image_rescaled, axis=1)

print 'X is'
print np.shape(X)
```

Comment: 31     X = np.append(X,hog_image_rescaled,axis=1)

Comment: ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: This is the error I got.

Comment: `X` has two dimensions. How many dimensions does `hog_image_rescaled` have?

Comment: There's no such thing as a numpy array with unknown dimension. Also don't confuse `np.empty` with the empty list `[]`. And don't use `np.append` in a loop. Better yet don't use `np.append` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
X = []    # use an 'empty' list
# hog_image = np.empty(shape)  # no point initializing these variables
# hog_image_rescaled = np.empty(shape)  # you just reassign them in the loop

for img in glob.glob("/home/madhuri/pythoncode/faces/*.jpg"):
   n= cv2.imread(img)
   gray = cv2.cvtColor(n, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
   hog_image = hog(gray, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(16, 16),     
                   cells_per_block=(3, 3), visualise=False)
   hog_image_rescaled = exposure.rescale_intensity(hog_image,
                                                   in_range=(0,10))  
   X.append(hog_image_rescaled)
```

Now `X` will be a list of rescaled images.  Those elements can now be concatenated on which ever dimension is appropriate:

```
np.concatenate(X, axis=1)
np.stack(X)
# etc
```

The list model of

```
alist = []
for ....
    alist.append(...)
```

does not translate well to arrays.  `np.append` is a cover for `np.concatenate`, and makes a new array, which is more expensive than list append.  And defining a good starting 'empty' array for such a loop is tricky.  `np.empty` is not appropriate:

```
In [977]: np.empty((2,3))
Out[977]: 
array([[1.48e-323, 1.24e-322, 1.33e-322],
       [1.33e-322, 1.38e-322, 1.38e-322]])
In [978]: np.append(_, np.zeros((2,1)), axis=1)
Out[978]: 
array([[1.48e-323, 1.24e-322, 1.33e-322, 0.00e+000],
       [1.33e-322, 1.38e-322, 1.38e-322, 0.00e+000]])
```